# PDField set default appearances multiple fonts - pdfbox 2.0

Tags: java, kotlin, fonts, pdfbox, glyph

There are two type of font glyphs

1. • (U+2022) Bullet Unicode Character which is supported by one Japanese font
2. U+200B - Zero Width Space which is supported by one Japanese font

Can we set `(PDField)field.defaultAppearance` to multiple fonts instead of one ?
My code snippet as follow:

```
val subsetFont=true
val pdType0Font1: PDType0Font = PDType0Font.load(inputPdf, File(bulletSportFontPth).inputStream(),subsetFont)
val pdType0Font2: PDType0Font = PDType0Font.load(inputPdf, File(widhtSpaceFontPath).inputStream(),subsetFont)

inputPdf.documentCatalog?.acroForm?.defaultResources?.add(pdType0Font1)
inputPdf.documentCatalog?.acroForm?.defaultResources?.add(pdType0Font2)
```

Now How can we set both appearances to PDField?

```
field.defaultAppearance = field.defaultAppearance.replace(Regex("/\\w*"),"/${pdType0Font1.name}")
field.defaultAppearance = field.defaultAppearance.replace(Regex("/\\w*"),"/${pdType0Font2.name}")
```

Comment: A field can have only one default appearance entry. Similarly there can be only one default appearance entry at form level.